# How to make an LED fuse status indicator?

Tags: led, indicator

I would like to have a LED indicator that is on when the fuse is not blown and off when the fuse is blown. This is not hard to do as you can place a LED on the output of the fuse. What makes it very hard for me is that the bus that is fused has variable voltage, from 5 to 24 V. This still can be done with the method I mentioned previously but the LED will not be of constant brightness, faint on 5 V and bright on 24 V.

Is there a circuit that lets me maintain the current on the LED regardless of voltage? I found out that 1 mA is the perfect brightness for me. Since this is only a fuse indicator I would like it to be as simple less components it can possibly be. I assume you would need some op-amps or transistors for this to work.

I have already done a bit of research,

Using [op-amps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kLTBIQNXuU)

[image]

and using [transistors](https://www.nexperia.com/applications/sub-systems/constant-current-source.html)

[image]

I do not know if these circuits works and it looks like I only need about 1 or 2 IC/components.

Comment: Some specialized analog comparator OP with digital output would work. Along the lines of https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1715.html#product-overview for 2 channels (but you obviously dont need speed or resolution so there will be cheaper options)

Comment: @Lundin what do you typically call these types of op amps? I buy my stuff from [lcsc.com](https://lcsc.com/products/Operational-Amplifier_516.html).  Seems like an isolation amplifier but those stuff are super expensive for the usecase im using

Comment: I just searched for "analog compartor digital output" and see what popped up (which was some highly specialized AD part)

Comment: Actually... maybe forget about that idea and use a zener which opens at 5V and then supply the LED through it. It will burn away a bit of energy though.

Comment: @Lundin i found a op-amp that is listed as dual supply and is pretty cheap, [LM358](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358b.pdf?ts=1657245046593&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM358B), will this work?

Comment: Isn't that just a standard dual channel op? As in variable output.

Comment: A pre-programmed linear constant current driver with enable pin?

Comment: @winny can you please give me an example part?

Comment: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/lighting-ics/linear-led-driver-ic/bcr-430u/ perhaps. Do a search as there are many out there.

Comment: i would use a cheap SMPS buck module, like an lm2596 to power the LED; no need for custom circuity or complications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just use an [LM334 programmable current device](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm334.pdf?ts=1657260482490) in series with the LED: -

[image]

A single resistor can program the current that flows and it can work down to 1 volts hence, it'll work on a 5 volt supply when put in series with an LED AND it'll work when the supply is 24 volts.

[image]

Comment: This indeed is a good IC pretty cheap and very simple to make, Does this IC heats up at 24v? assuming i want to lower my desired current to 0.5mA, the formula is Rset = 227uV/0.5mA = 0.454 ohms ? Isnt that a bit too low?

Comment: If you set for 1 mA and the LED drops 2 volts (about normal) and the supply is 24 volts, then 22 volts are across the LM334 with 1 mA flowing through it. That's a power dissipation of 22 mW in the LM334. In effect it is behaving like a 22 kohm resistor.

Comment: At normal ambient temperature (300 kelvin or about 27 degC), Vset is 227 uV x 300 = 68.1 mV.

Comment: `That's a power dissipation of 22 mW in the LM334. In effect it is behaving like a 22 kohm resistor` That is indeed negligible. Going back to my calculations that resistor would now be  Rset = 0.0681V/0.0005A = 136 ohms. Am i correct? That feels a lot more correct than the previous 0.4 ohms

Comment: @DrakeJest you didn't take into account the full meaning of Vset. Yes, I think 136 ohms seems correct. Look at the words in (2) at the middle of page 3 of the data sheet.

Answer (score 4):

LM334 is the ideal solution, although two transistors will do a plenty acceptable job in this application:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpAgZg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Graph of LED current vs. supply voltage]

Comment: this will indeed end up a lot more inexpensive the lm334 and probably less space consuming since the smallest package the lm334 have is an SOIC8, can this be done with mosfets though, as i have already have them on the board, although the 3904 is a very common part i dont have them on hand.

Comment: It gets better :) This circuit will take just about any bipolar silicon transistor. Doesn’t have to be 3904. I think the smallest LM334 package, in terms of footprint size, is TO-92. The circuit with transistors can use surface mount parts and can be 5x5mm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a circuit with a zener diode that will keep the LED current constant.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEY2EI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the differences to Lundins circuit.

The current through R1 needs to be bigger than the current through R2 and D2. But for 24 V instead of 5V the current through R1 is much bigger, so a lot of power is wasted in R1.

**I do not recommend this circuit, the other circuits by Andy Aka and Kuba are much better and waste much less power.**